# Timer application for Windows?

Tags: windows, timer

Can you suggest a good timer application for Windows?

It is surprising how useful a timer is for cooking, meditation, and for even giving oneself a timeout while working. I am not interested in any unwanted frills, just a simple light GUI timer that counts down and sounds when done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend this timer app.  It is very spartan and quite functional.

[Egg Timer 1.0](http://www.elegantpie.com/eggtimer.html)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Pretty useless for anything less than precisely on the hour, but [this clock](http://goneale.com/2009/06/09/fun-c-sharp-cuckoo-clock/) is just **awesome**

[image]

It silently ran in the background and chimed every hour by opening and closing the CD tray and playing a “cuckoo” sound.

Effectively turning their PC into a cuckoo clock.

(originally posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116/whats-your-favorite-harmless-computer-practical-joke) by Martin)

Comment: +1 for absurdity. For best results, print a picture of the cuckoo on a CD to leave in the tray ;-)

Comment: @RBerteig OMG! I wish I'd thought of that at the time! :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and after my search failed to find a solution I really liked, I wrote one.  It's called [SnapTimer](http://dan.hersam.com/software/snaptimer/index.html).

[image: SnapTimer screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[Light Calendar 1.0](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Light-Calendar.shtml)

or

[TimeLeft](http://www.downloadfile.org/Information_Management/Alarms_and_Reminders/TimeLeft.html)

Answer (score 2):

a great web alternative is http://e.ggtimer.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Taskbar Timer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/TaskbarTimer.aspx) with cool Win7-Taskbar integration (you can start timer from the Jumplist!).
Also you can look at XNote Stopwatch, but I just switched from it to Taskbar Timer and hope it will be better.

Comment: +1 Nice one! Its Taskbar integration makes it superior to all others

Answer (score 1):

I've used [MB-Timer](http://download.cnet.com/MB-Timer/3000-2350_4-10142201.html).  It is simple, lightweight, free and offers multiple timers at once.  Both count up and count down.  Written in flash I believe.  Not pretty, but functional.

The original website seems to be down, but it's available at the link I posted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php?option=com_rny_features&Itemid=35), but I wonder if it can't be done using Windows' Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

[Generic Countdown Timer](http://widgets.yahoo.com/widgets/generic-countdown-timer) requires Yahoo Widgets, but it really is the best countdown app I've used. The fact that it's in Yahoo means that you can even use it for Mac.